# hibernate не работает на aws & heroku

Tags: java, hibernate, развертывание, war

БД на aws rds. Локально все отлично работает, делаю деплой, делаю запрос и сразу же получаю стактрейс то самое на heroku. Делаю деплой на томкат(war).

structure

[image: struct]

pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.hemagglutinin</groupId>
    <artifactId>Gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.9.v20180320</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
```

hibernate util

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry =
                    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metaData =
                    new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
        }
    }

    public static Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

stack trace

```
22-Apr-2018 11:18:46.662 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [apiServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.hemagglutinin.gateway.dao.HibernateUtil
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.dao.ClientDAO.getSession(ClientDAO.java:36)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.dao.ClientDAO.getByUser(ClientDAO.java:26)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.service.ValidateService.userValidate(ValidateService.java:43)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.service.ValidateService.validateCustomerReq(ValidateService.java:22)
    at com.hemagglutinin.gateway.servlets.ApiServlet.doGet(ApiServlet.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Либо неверный класспатч прописывается, либо явно не хватает зависимостей, либо при сборки они не все пдхватываются. Вы пробовали запускать варник у себя на локале (не из под дебага)?

Comment: Как собираете проект? Ant, maven пр.?

Comment: @Chubatiy maven

Comment: В `dependency` есть ваша библиотека с классом `HibernateUtil`? И покажите `build` раздел вашего `pom.xml`. Также может быть проблема из-за вашего `configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")` в блоке `static`. Может он не видит файл `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Приведите структуру проекта

Comment: @Chubatiy обновил